# Failure Deploying Meteorjs app using developer account (not on Galaxy)

Tags: meteor, deployment, galaxy, unauthorized

After following the Meteorjs instructions and successfully creating an app, the deployment step failed. I am familiar with the developer account and the normal procedure.  The Error being provided is stating that I have unauthorized access to Galaxy and that I am attempting to deploy on it (this is the paid cloud service of Meteor released recently and not the testing cloud service of Meteor.com for developers). I am not understanding why this redirection is occurring. It would be helpful to point out the issue. The name of the app being deployed follows the format appname.meteor.com. Please also note that

- The developer-account dependency was installed
- The app was created through the Meteorjs dashboard
- I was also logged in from the console prior to deploying

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is very unclear, are you trying to deploy to Galaxy or not? What command are you running to deploy?

Comment: Hi, the problem definition and the title clearly state it is not Galaxy.  However a redirection from Meteor's free cloud hosting (meteor.com) to Galaxy is occurring when using the deploy command.  Hope this clarifies matters.

Comment: I know your title clearly states that, but what you're actually trying to do clearly demonstrates you're actually trying to use galaxy.

Comment: It's not my fault if the error said so. The auto-redirection was not caused by me. The question states that I am clearly using Meteor and i got redirected to  Galaxy by the CLI in the process. I did nothing to attempt deployment on Galaxy. I hope this clarifies matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like some clarity on the process you're attempting, however meteor killed free hosting in March of 2016 (three months ago at the time of this post).

[This post explains the details of MDG cancelling that service.](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-com-free-hosting-ends-march-25-2016/19308)

This means there is no longer a testing cloud service, which seems like what you're attempting to deploy to (can't tell as you've given no specifics on your process), there is only Galaxy.

Comment: I did not realise.  Is there a way to test Meteor apps online other than using Galaxy? Or at least if i test the app locally without deploying it, do i still get it to build like the final product? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you can still build it like the final product, but that's out of scope for your question. I wrote an article for how to deploy to digital ocean, you can check that out. There's also modulus which gives you a CLI tool as well - https://johngibby.com/blog/How_to_deploy_your_meteor.js_app_on_Digital_Ocean